# Installing Linux ubuntu with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, ubuntu-one

I want to install ubuntu alongside windows 10 but my laptop specifications are: 2G RAM, 300G HHD, 2.16 GHz dual processor. Could that work!? Because my computer is somewhat limited on resources! I winder if that couldn't affect the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu!
Yes, it works. You can only boot into Windows or Linux at a time, so they don't have to share the 2GB RAM. But you will need to split your HDD into 2 partitions (the Ubuntu installer will do guide you with this).

Comment: Okay thanks! That means when you're loged in one OS, another one is no longer accessing the RAM. Except the HDD which is portioned!

Comment: Exactly. At the boot, you will be asked if you want to boot Windows or Ubuntu and only the chosen one will use RAM until you reboot.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please also see the answer of @user953810 when you choose your version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ubuntu 18.04 or newer? if yes, it depends on your motherboard and you need 64 bit computer. If no, I recommend using ubuntu 16.04 LTS. you cannot download it on ubuntu.com, but on [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/?_ga=2.12472759.261454426.1557751162-1033387827.1557236627)

Comment: It is 64bit and I want to install the latest version Ubuntu 19.04.